# Geometric meaning of results obtained in (a) and (b)

Tags: functions

The task:
**Plot the function $\sqrt{1-x^2}$. What does it look like? What is the geometric meaning of the results you obtained in (a) and (b)?**
Can anybody help me with **geometric mean**? I can't understand what i need to do.

[image]

I've plotted this by Wolfram, i think that a and b is in 1.0 and -1.0.

Comment: You need to plot the function, then say what it looks like.

Comment: update pls, i've edited the question.

Comment: @Semiclassical, yeah thats first two questions, but i don't know what is to the geometric meaning..

Comment: @aine: I think `(a)` and `(b)` are some important parts of the problem.

Comment: With regards to that picture, it's a little deceptive due to the aspect ratio. [This may help](http://wolfr.am/1nMR8dH)

Comment: aine, if you write $y=\sqrt {1-x^2},$ then square both sides and put all the variables on one side, what do you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation $y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ can be rewritten as $\sqrt{(x-0)^2+(y-0)^2}=1$. The LHS describes the distance from the point $(0,0)$ to a point $(x,y)$, and the RHS says that this distance is a constant. Therefore the distance from the origin to any point on the function is $1$. The geometric shape that has a constant distance from a particular point is a **circle**. In this case, the function describes a (semi-)circle with centre $(0,0)$ and radius $1$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

The equation you have in question is $y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$.  What would happen if you square both sides of the equation?  You get a very familiar geometric object.  Once you determine what it is, you can conclude that $y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ is just the upper part of it.  And, $y=-\sqrt{1-x^2}$ is the lower part of it.